# Location issue from API

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, core-location

I'm facing an issue while trying to get my coordinate from api

I'm trying to create a constant class that includes all my URL's after that I create another class called location includes two variables latitude and longitude and i create a function to get the lat and long in the main control and save it into location class so i can use it in the url in the constant class

The problem is if I try to print the coordinate the latitude and longitude
from the function it appears correctly in the output but when I try to use in the constant class it's showing `nil`

my constant class

```
import Foundation
 import Alamofire

 let Base_Url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
  let lats = "lat="
  let lons = "&lon="
  let AppId = "&appid=951191ec976939570dc1aa8e0b5ed6bd"
  var lat = locationClass.sharedinstance.lat
   var lon = locationClass.sharedinstance.lon
    let CurrentWeatherUrl = "\(Base_Url)\(lats)37.785834000000001\(lons)-122.406417\(AppId)"

   let FourCastWeatherUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=21.5169444&lon=39.2191667&cnt=10&appid=951191ec976939570dc1aa8e0b5ed6bd"

  typealias DownloadCompleted = () -> ()
```

location class

```
import CoreLocation

  class locationClass {
static var sharedinstance = locationClass()
private init () {}
var lat: Double!
var lon: Double!
   }
```

the function that getting the latitude and longitude

```
func currentLocationAuth(){
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse{
        currentlocation = locationmanager.location
        locationClass.sharedinstance.lat = currentlocation.coordinate.latitude
        locationClass.sharedinstance.lon = currentlocation.coordinate.longitude
        print(locationClass.sharedinstance.lat,locationClass.sharedinstance.lon)
    }else{
        locationmanager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            currentLocationAuth()
    }
```

why when I try to print the value from main control showing but when I try to use it in constant class showing empty

Comment: I think this should work fine if you access the lat long variable after the currentLocationAuth method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm not so sure what you mean by a constant class...but something ie a function or an init method has to trigger/initialize those constants. If that happens **before** your singleton locationClass is loaded into the memory then obviously you'll get `nil`.
2. So the suggestion is to simply call: `locationClass.sharedinstance` before feeding your long/lat so it would initialize your singleton.

Additionally in Swift 3, the convention is to simply use 'shared' and avoid using 'sharedInstance'

Comment: thanks @honey  , what i did is i called the function in did appear function and i found that its getting optional values that's why the link was returning error so i add ! and it works fine now